# How Do I Revert an MKS Change Package

Tags: version-control, mks, mks-integrity

I have a branch of a large project with a couple of change packages on it.  I would like to undo one of them.  In Subversion, this task is trivial, esp with a tool such as tortoisesvn - select the revision(s) from the history and undo the changes.  I cannot find a way to do this in MKS.  I cannot even find a way to traverse my sandbox to an earlier revision.  Can anyone please offer some guidance?  I'd rather not have to create a second sandbox, diff the two trees and copy select changes from one to the other, which is what a colleague (who wanted to do the same thing) suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this functionality does not currently exist in Integrity.

**Disclosure:**  I work for PTC Integrity Technical Support.

Comment: Thanks.  Not the answer I wanted to hear, but nice to have it from the horse's mouth, as it were.  Any idea if it will ever be included or can you not say?

Comment: Any answer I could give would be complete speculation.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@mlizak_PTC

Do you then know somethig about

Change Package->Discard

Discard Change Package Entry...

Somehow the help to the change package functions did not enlighten me :)

@Jon

The only way I know to get the same as "traversing the sandbox to an earlier revision" is when you have a well defined checkpoint resp. project revision which you can retarget your sandbox to (build sandbox) and then resync.

You can then retarget your sandbox again to the state it was before (Mainline or a variant) and see the differences to the current state of the project.

If had to rely on changepackage info I would redirect the output
of the command 'si viewcp' to a file and try to sort that information out.

eg.

```
si viewcp --fields=configpath,creationdate,id,location,member,membertype,project,revision,sandbox,state,timestamp,type,user 132:1
```

From the gui you can also select all entries from a change package detail view and copy them to clipboard.